# WebStorm: TypeScript source-mapping in debug mode doesn't work

Tags: typescript, debugging, jestjs, webstorm, source-maps

I have a test-suit and a class under test, both are written in TypeScript. I am in a node-project and I run the Jest-Test from WebStorm in Debug-Mode. When I set a break point in the test WebStorm stopps exactly where I want. But when I step into the class under test the debugger jumps to the last line of it's .ts file. In the debug view I see that the linenumbers doesn't correspond to the ts-file. I seems like the source-mapping doesn't work for my class under test.

**Q: How to fix the source-mapping?**

The project structure is a follows:

```
project-root
  /projects/my-node-project/src
      /services         //here is the production code
      /specs            //here are the test-suits
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your `jest.config.js` - what does it look like? Do you have `collectCoverage` enabled in it?
If the source file is instrumented for coverage, the generated code can't be correctly mapped to source; it's a well known limitation (not specific to WebStorm,BTW)

Comment: Thanks that solves the problem!  Do you know of an option/way in WebStorm to override `collectCoverage` for launch-configurations that where started in Debug mode?